# How to create a vertical navigation bar with dots in beamer, Latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I see several beamer templates that use some dots as a navigation bar for each section, in the header part. My question is, how I can create a navigation bar, vertically, on the right side of each slide, for all slides without separating in sections (like being a progression bar with dots)?

Thank you for any help!

### Edit:

I have this horizontal bar with dots:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\definecolor{frenchblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.45, 0.73}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage{tikz}


\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
\leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=4.8ex,dp=0.125ex]{palette}%
        \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{}{\hskip0pt plus1filll}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  }
}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot}{%
    \if\insertsectionheadnumber1
        \tikz \fill[frenchblue] circle (1.5pt);
    \else
        \tikz \fill[frenchblue] circle (1.5pt);
    \fi
}
\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}{%
    \if\insertsectionheadnumber1
        \tikz \draw[frenchblue] circle (1.5pt);
    \else
        \tikz \draw[frenchblue] circle (1.5pt);
    \fi



\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Now I want it just to be vertically on the right side, or horizontally on the bottom...?

Thanks!

Comment: related questions: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/396263/up-to-down-progress-bar/397208#397208 https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139149/navigation-frames-in-sidebar/326543#326543

Comment: @samcarter , yes, I'm thinking something like on the second link but I want to keep only the dots and possible equally spaced (not separated with sections).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slight variation of [Navigation frames in sidebar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139149/navigation-frames-in-sidebar/326543#326543)

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% removing section names from navigation
\makeatletter
\def\sectionentry#1#2#3#4#5{% section number, section title, page
    \ifnum#5=\c@part%
    \beamer@section@set@min@width
    \box\beamer@sectionbox\hskip1.875ex%
    \beamer@xpos=0\relax%
    \beamer@ypos=0\relax%
    \ht\beamer@sectionbox=1.875ex%
    \dp\beamer@sectionbox=0ex%
    \fi\ignorespaces}


\def\insertnavigation#1{%
  \vbox{{%
    \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{section in head/foot}%
    \beamer@xpos=0\relax%
    \beamer@ypos=1\relax%
    \hbox to #1{\hskip.3cm\setbox\beamer@sectionbox=\hbox{\kern1sp}%
      \ht\beamer@sectionbox=1.875ex%
      \dp\beamer@sectionbox=0.75ex%
        \hskip-1.875ex plus-1fill%
        \global\beamer@section@min@dim\z@
        \dohead%
        \beamer@section@set@min@width
      \box\beamer@sectionbox\hfil\hskip.3cm
      \hfill
      }%
  }}}    

\makeatother

% Set Theme
\usetheme[width=0.8cm]{Marburg}
\setbeamercolor*{mini frame}{fg=red,bg=blue}
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar canvas right}[vertical shading][top=white,bottom=white]

% insert dots in sidebar
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar right}{\hskip0.3cm\rotatebox{270}{\insertnavigation{.98\paperheight}}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}{Outline}
        \tableofcontents
    \end{frame}

    \section{sec1}
    \subsection{s1}
    \begin{frame}{frame1.1}
        blah, blah, blah
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}{frame1.2}
        blah, blah, blah
    \end{frame}

    \section{sec2}
        \subsection{s2}
    \begin{frame}{frame2.1}
        blah, blah, blah
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}{frame2.2}
        blah, blah, blah
    \end{frame}

    \section{sec3}
    \subsection{s3}
    \begin{frame}{frame3.1}
        blah, blah, blah
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}{frame3.2}
        blah, blah, blah
    \end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, it's almost what I wanted, just without the blue bar as a background of dots :( I would like to remove it and to keep only the dots!

Comment: @user4712458 please see my edited answer

Comment: Yes, it looks perfect :) Thank you so much!

Comment: @user4712458 you're welcome!