# "indicators" of where we are on the slides

Tags: beamer, themes, mini-frames

I have a curiosity: some beamer themes (for instance, Ilmenau), have "indicators" of where we are on the slides (I dont know the correct term), are some balls that represent the number of slides and the current slide. Other themes (for instance, PaloAlto) dont have. Is there any way to add this to any theme?

---

I want to add the miniframes at the top.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\title{Os Teoremas de Philip Hall e uma caracterização para Grupos Solúveis}
\author[Lucas Corrêa Lopes]{Lucas Corrêa Lopes\\ {\small Orientador: André Luiz Martins Pereira}}
\date{}
\institute{Unversidade Federal Rural do Rio de Janeiro}

%Tema 1:

\usetheme{PaloAlto}
\logo{\includegraphics[scale=0.26]{logo_ufrrj(1).png} }
\setbeamercolor{logo}{bg=white}
\usecolortheme{orchid}
\usefonttheme{serif}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes it is possible to add miniframes (that the name for the small bullets) to other themes, but usually it is easier the other way round and add elements that you like to a theme that already has miniframes.

Comment: If you can make a specific example how the output should look like, we might be able to help you.

Comment: If your real question is how to use miniframes in the sidebar, then have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153729/use-bullets-from-mini-frames-in-sidebar-outer-theme or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139149/navigation-frames-in-sidebar

Comment: I put my specific case.

Comment: I'll read your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the miniframe navigation to the headline:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\title{Os Teoremas de Philip Hall e uma caracterização para Grupos Solúveis}
\author[Lucas Corrêa Lopes]{Lucas Corrêa Lopes\\ {\small Orientador: André Luiz Martins Pereira}}
\date{}
\institute{Unversidade Federal Rural do Rio de Janeiro}

%Tema 1:

\usetheme{PaloAlto}
\logo{\includegraphics[scale=0.26]{example-image-duck}}
\setbeamercolor{logo}{bg=white}
\usecolortheme{orchid}
\usefonttheme{serif}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{frametitle}
    \ifx\beamer@sidebarside\beamer@lefttext%
    \else%
      \hfill%
    \fi%
    \ifdim\beamer@sidebarwidth>0pt%  
      \usebeamercolor[bg]{logo}%
      \vrule width\beamer@sidebarwidth height \beamer@headheight%
      \hskip-\beamer@sidebarwidth%
      \hbox to \beamer@sidebarwidth{\hss\vbox to
        \beamer@headheight{\vss\hbox{\color{fg}\insertlogo}\vss}\hss}%
    \else%
      \vrule width0pt height \beamer@headheight%  
    \fi%
    \begin{minipage}[b][\beamer@headheight][c]{\dimexpr\paperwidth-\beamer@sidebarwidth}%
            \insertnavigation{\dimexpr\paperwidth-\beamer@sidebarwidth}
    \end{minipage}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{title}
\subsection{title}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{title}
\subsection{title}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Greg You're welcome!